# Laravel command not found

Tags: ubuntu, laravel

So I installed laravel on my server.
Now I added the path using:

```
sudo PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Now laravel command works fine for root/sudo users but not for normal users.
I want normal users to be able to use the command as well.
Currently it's not found at all(as a normal user)

```
laravel: command not found
```

Is there a way to give all users access(or users with the group laravel for example)

I'm running UBUNTU 14.04

Comment: The command is `artisan` not `laravel`.

Comment: @user3117036 I do use the laravel command for example for creating a new project etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add path,  you don't need to use sudo. Just do it as normal user,  ~$PATH=$PATH:~/.... 
or just edit ~.profile and add it to make it permanent so that when you login again,  you won't need to repeat

Comment: I tried adding path as normal user but I'm still getting laravel: command not found.

Comment: Why not put in the the user bash profile. And relogin

Answer (score 3):

You want to symbolically link the executable into the system user's default `$PATH`. The most appropriate place to link it is in `/usr/local/bin`. You can create the link like so:

```
$ sudo ln -s /full/path/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel /usr/local/bin/laravel
```

Note: This will not allow users to execute `laravel` if they do not have sufficient privileges to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a Laravel Development Environment through pre-installed composer:

Type the following command on your command shell:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Then on typing '*which composer*' can get you the path:
On my system it is :

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

After getting the path,copy the path and cd into it through your command shell:
Then type:

```
laravel new project
```

A new laravel development environment will be set up. You can see a new folder created once you visit that path.